# How to remove specific country in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, country

Can someone tell how can I remove the specific country from woocommerce. There is option in woocommerce that said selling locations with All countries and specific.

However I want to sell to all countries except the 1 country that is US for example! then how can I remove US from the countries list. As if I use "specific countries" option then I will have to add all the countries except the US which is longer process.

Is there any code you can help me with that I can put into functions of theme so that US country will not appear in the list of countries during checkout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this following snippet

```
function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) 
{
   unset($country["US"]);
   return $country; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
```

Reference
http://www.boopathirajan.com/remove-specific-country-woocommerce-country-list/

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that :)

Comment: Country codes and names list: [https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/i18n/countries.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/i18n/countries.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep an array of countries, but you only have the keys, do something like this:

```
function woo_remove_specific_country( $countries ) {

    global $woocommerce;

    // default do not limit
    $limited_countries = array_values(array_flip($countries));

    // Country array to keep
    $eu = $woocommerce->countries->get_european_union_countries( );

    // keep countries, sort them out of the full array to keep the names
    $found   = array_filter($countries, function($item) use ($eu) {
        return in_array($item, $eu);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); // USE_KEY is essential cause we are filtering the language codes

    // return the found countries
    return $found;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
```